# Applying translation, rotation and scale to THREE.BoxGeometry(..)

Tags: three.js

I am creating a scene with several thousand cubes, each of which can be translated, scaled and rotated.

Initially, I tried creating a cube geometry, applying the transformations, creating a mesh with my material and adding it to the scene. That worked but was very slow because of all the draw calls.

So now, for all the cubes, I create a `THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1)`, and merge it with a single `THREE.Geometry()` each time before finally creating a material and a single mesh and adding it to my scene.

The performance is drastically improved but I don't know how to apply a translation (XYZ), scale (XYZ) and rotation (quaternion) to each box before merging it.  Can someone point me at the right syntax?

Secondly, if I merge my geometry like this, is there still a way to pick out a single box with a raycaster? Typically I've used the object name on the mesh but that's not relevant anymore.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to use instancing ( `THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry`) and GPU Picking. Study those topics, and see the three.js examples.

Comment: I looked at the example here: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=inst#webgl_interactive_instances_gpu but on my system at least (MacBook Pro, macOS Mojave, AMD Radeon R9 M370X 2048 MB) it barely managed 0.1Hz - all the other examples work as expected at a solid 60Hz.

Comment: That example is too confusing, IMO. Instancing is the correct approach in your case.

Comment: Ok - I have instancing working but the other piece i need is picking.  For some reason, on my system the examples that do GPU picking like https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes_gpu.html and https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_instances_gpu.html have frame rates less than 1 so they are not usable 

Is there another approach one can use for picking instanced geometry?

Comment: FWIW, this is the line that kills the frame rate: 
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes_gpu.html#L209 Not clear if its just my system - don't easily have a way to check elsewhere.

Comment: Make a new question, link to a live example that demonstrates the problem, and perhaps @gman will have an idea why gpu picking is slow on your machine.